# How to differentiate between in-page links and out-of-page links

Tags: html, css, documentation, usability

I have a documentation page, and an example paragraph may look like this:

> For more information on retailers, please see our [Retailer section](http://asdf.com), and to see an example retailer, [click here](http://asdf.com).

What is a good way to differentiate the two links for an end user, the first link being within the documentation, and the second link going to an external site. I thought about using the "link to external site" icon -- https://fontawesome.com/icons/external-link-alt?style=solid --

[image]

-- but to me that feels more like a "open link in new tab" icon, which has nothing to do with the above (both will appear in the same window the user is currently in.

What would be a better way to communicate that?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the font awesome 'link' icon on external links. https://fontawesome.com/icons/link?style=solid

And just leave all other links as is. It makes sense to me but I think this is just a matter of opinion. :) This is more of a business/design decision than a technical issue. From what I've seen most sites don't specify between the two.